# Is a mocked bean (@MockBean) mocked before the Spring Context loads the actual Spring Bean?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

Let's use the following as an example.

```
@Autowired
@MockBean
private Foo foobar;
```

Does the Spring Context load the class `Foo` first, and then apply the mock? Or does the `@Mockbean` get detected somehow, and Spring creates and applies the mock instead of loading the class `Foo` into the Spring Context. I have a suspicion that it is the latter, but I would like confirmation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spring will throw an exception.

Let's define the class Foo.

```
@Component
public class Foo {
    public Foo() {
        System.out.println("I am not a mock");
    }
}
```

Whenever testing using `@Autowired`, spring injects an instance of Foo and the constructor will print `"I am not a mock"`, as in the code below.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Main.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Autowired
    Foo foo;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
}
```

On the other hand, using @MockBean, spring will not create the real bean and the message in the constructor will not be printed. This scenario is represented by the following code.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Main.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class FooTest {

    @MockBean
    Foo foo;
    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
}
```

However, when you try to use both annotations together, spring will throw a `BeanCreationException` caused by an `IllegalStateException`. It means that the field foo cannot have an existing value. This scenario will happen in executing the code below:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Main.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class FooTest {
   // this will not work
    @Autowired
    @MockBean
    Foo foo;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
}
```

And the stack trace will be something like:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not inject field: com.tbp.Foo com.FooTest.foo; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The field com.tbp.Foo com.FooTest.foo cannot have an existing value
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor.inject(MockitoPostProcessor.java:413) ~[spring-boot-test-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
```